# heredoc format and its implementation

Tags: php, heredoc

i wrote the following code...

```
<?php

$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if($conn)
echo "connection established";

mysql_select_db("moviesite");

$que="select * from movie";
$result=mysql_query($que,$conn);
?>

<html>
<title>movie database</title>
<body>
<table border=1 align=center>
<th colspan=2>
PEOPLE<a href='movie.php?action=add & id='>[ADD]</a>
</th>

<?php
$ta_row=<<<eod
    <tr>
    <td>
    $mov_name
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href='movie.php?action=edit & id=$mov_id'>[EDIT]</a>
    <a href='movie.php?action=delete & id=$mov_id'>[DELETE]</a>
    <td>
    </tr>
eod;

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$mov_id=$row["id"];
$mov_name=$row["name"];
echo $ta_row;
}
?>
```

now the above code didnt print the name or the id of the movie(the fields were blank)...so i cut and paste $ta_row inside the while loop after the definition of $mov_id and $mov_name...this sorted out all problems...but my question is why did the code fail earlier...as it is i was outputting ta_row after defining $mov_id and $mov_name so if $ta_row is just a string its content variables should have got changed...why didnt they change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a heredoc is just like any other string - it's value is fixed when you declare it. If the variables `$mov_id` and `$mov_name` weren't set when you declared `$ta_row`, you can't use them in `$ta_row`.

If you want to do something like you tried to do in the first place, you would have to use something like [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) - replace place-holders in the original string with the actual values you want to display.

Consider this:

```
$myVar = "Some string containing a $var";
$var = 'Variable';
echo $myVar;
// Outputs: Some string containing a
```

Now this:

```
$var = 'Variable';
$myVar = "Some string containing a $var";
echo $myVar;
// Outputs: Some string containing a Variable
```

...Heredocs behave *exactly* like a double-quoted string (from this point of view, at least).

Alternatively you could do this:

```
$myVar = 'Some string containing a $var';
$var = 'Variable';
echo $myVar;
// Outputs: Some string containing a $var
echo str_replace('$var',$var,$myVar);
// Outputs: Some string containing a Variable
```

...because `$myVar` is now single-quoted, `$var` appears in it literally. Then when you run `str_replace()`, it is replaced with the value of `$var`, instead of the literal string.

It's probably worth you re-reading [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work when you had it before the loop because it was trying to use the value of the variables `$mov_id` and `$mov_name` as they existed right then. Since they weren't defined at that point in the code, there was nothing to add in there. After that, `$ta_row` was simply a variable that contained a string, and only a string -- no variables, of the HTML.

If you'd like to move it out of the loop, use some placeholders like ##MOV_ID## and ##MOV_NAME## then you can just

```
echo str_replace(array('##MOV_ID##', '##MOV_NAME##', array($mov_id, $mov_name), $ta_row);
```

to get the desired result